# Merge vector points with point name into field name ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, attribute-table, merge

I am merging several points gathered on Google Earth after converting KML into a shapefile. I would like to have in the output file (merged) a field indicating the file name of the corresponding source points (the original single points that I want to merge).

Is that possible in ArcGIS?

Comment: By Layer do you mean you exported the KML as a shapefile? What version of arcmap are you using? What do you mean by "source point"? Please edit your question with these details

Comment: How did you perform the kmz to shapefile conversion (software, website, or tool)?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily achieve this with modelbuilder: use a featureclass iterator to iterate over your shapefiles, this feeds into an add field, then calculate tool using inline substitution from a parse path tool to store the file name.

Once you have run that you can run a merge tool bring them altogether into a single dataset.

Basically read the help file and find out about modelbuilder.